# Find biggest array from a multi dimensional array by count in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift, swift3

I has a multi dimensional array. It can have more than one array in itself. Sometimes maybe 5 or 6. Now I want to get the largest array from my multi dimensional array by using array size. I don't know how to achieve this. Hence i'm posting here. Thanks in advance.

For example:

[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]]

Comment: Can you show your nested array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are looking for the longest subarray within the given
array then you can simply use `max(by:)` with a comparison 
using the array count:

```
let a = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"], ["k"]]

let longestSubArray = a.max(by: { $0.count < $1.count })!

print(longestSubArray)
// ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
```

Here I have assumed that `a` is not empty, otherwise `max(by:)`
will return `nil`. If that can happen, use optional binding:

```
if let longestSubArray = a.max(by: { $0.count < $1.count }) {
    print(longestSubArray)
} else {
    print("a is empty")
}
```

*Remark:* `Array` is a `RandomAccessCollection` and therefore getting
its `count` is a `O(1)` operation.

If you need both the longest element and its index in the containing
array then you can apply the above to `a.enumerated()`:

```
if let (idx, longest) = a.enumerated().max(by: { $0.element.count < $1.element.count }) {
    print("longest subarray", longest)
    print("at index", idx)
}
```

If there is more than one subarray with the maximal length then the above
solutions will return one of them. [@dfri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41778050/1187415) shows how to get *all*
subarrays with the maximal length.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the most obvious (not the shortest) way:

I am just looping through the array and checking the size of the array inside

```
let anArray = [["Hello", "This", "is"], ["Hello", "This", "is", "a", "5"], ["Hello", "This", "is", "a", "6", "!"]])

var max = 0

for array in anArray
{
    if array.count > max
    {
        max = array.count
    }
}

print(max)
```

You could use an array of AnyObject or something else instead of string for your own purpose

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, just have the following update:

I made this function:

```
func getLongestArray(anArr:[[String]]) -> [String]
{
    var maxArr = [String]()

    for array in anArr
    {
        if(array.count > maxArr.count)
        {
            maxArr = array
        }
    }

    return maxArr
}
```

And then where appropriate, make this call

```
let anArray = [["Hello", "This", "is"], ["Hello", "This", "is", "a", "5"], ["Hello", "This", "is", "a", "6", "!"]]

print(getLongestArray(anArr: anArray))
```

This should return the longest array although assuming you at least have an array of size > 0

Comment: this only gets the size of the array. I need the longest array. anyway thank you.

Comment: how do you define the longest array ? The array with the most strings in it or the total character count inside the array ? I did the former

Comment: your code just return only the max number - but the requested answer was the array itself

Comment: I you happen to encounter a huge array where all subarrays happens to be somewhat sorted in increasing order w.r.t. to `count`, the solution above will use a huge amount of unnecessary wasteful array assignments (`maxArr = array`). A more sensible approach would be to simply track the _index_ of the longest subarray, and after exiting the `for` loop, simply return the subarray corresponding to the "max" index.

Comment: @dfri: I don't think that the assignment is a problem due to the copy-on-write implementation of arrays. The loop variable `array` is already a copy of the array element, as are `$0`, `$1` in my `a.max(by: { $0.count < $1.count })` or `$0` in your second solution.

Comment: @MartinR I see, thanks. Just double-checking: so comparing looping over the elements of an array (e.g. `array` over `anArr` above) is comparable to a pre-defined array property (e.g. `maxArr` above) repeatedly being assigned copies of arrays (even if they are monotonically increasing in size; e.g. as in the assignment of the `array` iterate in the `for` loop above)? (Due to copy-on-write for arrays `maxArr` simply acts like a reference with its tip moved around to different existing stored arrays, as long as it does not mutate itself?)

Comment: @dfri: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. But an assignment `maxArray = array` copies only the `struct Array` elements, not the backing store. This article https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html is instructive, it shows how you can implement your own copy-on-write value type.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, that instructive article answers my somewhat nondescript question.

Answer (score 2):

The `max(by:)` approach used in [@MartinR:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41777721/4573247) is the fit for purpose solution here, but (as I commonly write :), for the joy of alternatives, you could also "manually" fold over the indices over your array to find the index which corresponds to the longest sub-array (maximum `.count`):

```
let arr = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]]

if arr.count > 0 {
    let longestSubArray = arr[
        arr.indices.reduce(0) { arr[$1].count > arr[$0].count ? $1 : $0 } // (*)
    ]
    print(longestSubArray) // ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
}

/* (*) Alternatively:
arr.indices.lazy.map { arr[$0].count }.max() ?? 0 */
```

In case you'd like to find the subset of subarrays that have the largest count (which may not be a single one), you could use a similar approach combined with `filter`:

```
// two longest subarrays with same count
let arr = [["a", "b", "c"],
           ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
           ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q"]]

let maxSubArrayCount = arr.lazy.map { $0.count }.max() // thanks @muescha (+)
let longestSubArrays = arr.filter { $0.count == maxSubArrayCount }
print(longestSubArrays) /* [["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"], 
                            ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q"]] */

/* (+) Alternatively:
let maxSubArrayCount = arr.reduce(0) { $1.count > $0 ? $1.count : $0 } */
```

Comment: your first code snipped  is broken with this array `let arr = [["a", "b", "c"], ["2"], ["d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]]` it returns `["2"]`

Comment: shorter: `let maxSubArrayCount = arr.map{$0.count}.max()`

Comment: @muesha it is shorter shorter, but will use two passes over the array (as compared to the single pass of the `reduce` approach). Possibly `arr.lazy.map { $0.count }.max()` would result in only a single pass though.

Comment: but the reduce need to call the count twice for the array?

Comment: I believe (the slightly modified version of your proposal) `arr.lazy.map { $0.count }.max()` is the best approach here, in the end; imo it has slightly better semantics than the `reduce` approach. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: and b/c i don't understand the magic behind the first code snippet with the `arr.indices.reduce(0) {...}` i tried it again with this `let arr = [["1","2","3"],["1","2"],["2"]]` and i get this wrong result `["1", "2"]`

Comment: with your edit now it works and makes sense for me :)