# Find the all string in array are greater than length 4 in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777555/find-biggest-array-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-count-in-swift).
I am trying to get string who length is greater than length 4.
Example :

```
["Rama", "Bhima", "Budhaa"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [count method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3003522-count) to find out if a string has more than 4 characters and [filter method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) to create a list of strings that meet the greater than 4 character condition:

```
let strings: [String] = ["Rama", "Bhima", "Budhaa"]
let result = strings.filter { str in str.count > 4 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need all values that meet your criteria, try;

```
let strings: [String] = ["Rama", "Bhima", "Budhaa"]
let filteredStrings = strings.filter { $0.count > 4 } // ["Bhima", "Budhaa"]
```

If you need only the first value that meet your criteria, try;

```
let strings: [String] = ["Rama", "Bhima", "Budhaa"]
let filteredString = strings.first(where: { $0.count > 4 }) // optional("Bhima")
```